# Selecting Data from a column where NULLs and strings exist

Tags: sql-server

Hi i have a query that appears to be pulling in 'Not Set' twice:

[image]

Now after a few checks i know it is because the currentstage column has NULLS and the string 'Not Set'stored in the table. So below yields 3 strings of 'Not set' and 195 NULLS forced to 'Not Set'.
But what i actually want to see is 198 x 'Not Sets' in my #TempCircCount. How can this be done please?

My Failing code is here:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCircCount') is not null
DROP TABLE #TempCircCount
SELECT 
    ISNULL(cirRep.CurrentStage, 'Not Set') AS CurrentStage,
    COUNT(ISNULL(cirRep.CurrentStage, 'Not Set')) AS Circuits
INTO #TempCircCount
FROM 
    [QuoteBase].[dbo].[CircuitReports] cirRep
RIGHT JOIN 
    Quotebase.dbo.Circuits cir ON cir.[PW Number] = CirRep.[PWNumber]
WHERE 
    Cir.Status='New Circuit Order'
GROUP BY CurrentStage 
ORDER BY CurrentStage

SELECT 
    ISNULL(CurrentStage, 'Not Set') AS [CurrentStage], 
    Circuits AS Circuits
FROM #TempCircCount
GROUP BY CurrentStage,  Circuits
ORDER BY CurrentStage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe simply changing

```
GROUP BY CurrentStage
```

to

```
GROUP BY ISNULL(cirRep.CurrentStage, 'Not Set')
```

would work.

The `GROUP BY` uses `CurrentStage` from one of your table fields (i.e. `cirRep.CurrentStage`) instead of the field in the select. SQL server disallows grouping by a field in the select.

I also recommend **not** using the same names for your output fields as already existing fields for exactly this reason.

Comment: Thank you the advice is appreciated and the solution sorted out my problem.